# Paste link VBA code not working

Tags: vba, excel

My paste link does not seem to work and is giving me a select method of range class failed on the specified line. I don't seem to be able to diagnose this error.

```
Sub CustomizedInputFixedoutputnotworking()

 Dim rng As Range, _
 inp As Range, _
 ws As Worksheet

Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else

Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B2:N5").Select ' Code does not work at this line

Worksheets("Sheet 2").Paste Links:=True

End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the name really have a space or is it "Sheet2"?  Also the paste needs a range to anchor.  `Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B6").PasteSpecial Links:=True`

Comment: i eliminated the spaces and adjusted the sheet names accordingly but still gives me the same error message! @ScottCraner

Comment: Are these hyperlinks or formulas you are hoping to copy/paste, and why does a normal paste not work?

Comment: they are just numbers . normal paste works but i want to implement a paste link! @Hambone

Comment: I got it...  the one thing I still don't understand, are you copying B2:N5 to the location that is clicked, or is that the destination you want the new formulas pasted?

Comment: try to add this line `Worksheets("Sheet 2").activate` before your line `Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("B2:N5").Select`

Comment: destination to be pasted~! @Hambone

Comment: I think I see the issue, then...  posting my attempted solution.

Comment: I am getting a application /object defined error on the paste link line @Fadi

Comment: @Niva, I don't understand your code , but you can't select any range if its parent worksheet is not the active sheet

Comment: you set rng and don't use it?

Comment: i am using the range to copy. the range to copy is on another sheet and it is being pasted on another sheet @Fadi

Comment: @Niva, OK give some time to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub CustomizedInputFixedoutputnotworking()

 Dim rng As Range, _
 inp As Range, _
 ws As Worksheet

Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else

  rng.Copy ' add this line to copy the range that user selected before (with InputBox)
  Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate ' add this line to activate the target worksheet, because select method (the next line) only work in the active sheet
  Range("B2:N5").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True


End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

NOTE: Copy method will fail if the user select non-contiguous ranges for example A1 and B2, the simple way (not the complete way) to avoid that is by using:

```
Set rng = Union(rng, rng)
If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: @Niva, You are welcome,but why you `set inp=selection` , you don't need it in this code and if you want to select it again at the end of the code? I can change the code now.

Comment: yupyup made a mistake there

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that you selected the text but never copied it to the clipboard.  Even if you did copy it, the `.Select` method would have changed your destination.

I am hopeful a simple change to the `.Copy` method will resolve your issue.  If not, let me know:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:N5").Copy 
Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
```

-- edit --

Based on the comment that the selected range is the "copy" (source) and B2:N5 is the destination, try this:

```
rng.Copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:N5").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
```

Comment: sorry b2:n5 is the location where the data is pasted. copy range is user selected

Comment: getting a method of paste fail on the paste link again.